# The Symbol "&" in GetAsyncKeyState

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000)
```

What is the meaning of "&" in the if statement above? Why we need to use it?

Comment: Loop up *bitwise operators* and how to use them with *bitmasks*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 6):

```
GetAsyncKeyState(key)
```

will return you 16-bit value.

Such `1010010101110110`

The highest order bit contains the key state.

***1***010010101110110 highest order bit in bold.

Since we are only interested in the value on the highest order and mask the rest,  we do the following operation  `&` **bitwise and operation**.

0x8000 is hexadecimal represendtation of **1**000000000000000.

### key & 0x8000

==>

### **1**010010101110110 *GetAsyncKeyState(key)*

### &

### **1**000000000000000 *0x8000*

Result:

### **1**000000000000000 *A value evaluated as true*

As the example shows, we mask the bits other than the highest order bit which is set if the key is pressed otherwise zero. If block will  be executed if the key is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this @Cahit. I discovered that the synchronous API doesn't work as expected when using a WindowProc callback so this was very useful. One minor comment, your binary examples are all 17 bits. Was that intentional?

Comment: It was a mistake, not intentional. I should correct that. Thanks @JamieGarroch-MVP.

Answer (score 1):

Checking alt key is down or not.

And it is `bitwise and` operator.